# KIE Server execution using Java API

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie

I have simple Business process with rule executed before and after RestService WorkItem
[BPM Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9oTJ.png)

I also defined the Rest Work Handler definition in the settings.
[Rest Work Handler Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVlJa.png) [Install Rest Work Item Handler.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn4h4.png)

Using Java KIE API calling RuleServicesClient to execute Rules and BPM Process.

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

        CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new EnteredCredentialsProvider(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        KieServicesConfiguration kieServicesConfig = KieServicesFactory.newRestConfiguration(KIE_SERVER_URL, credentialsProvider);

        // Set the Marshaling Format to JSON. Other options are JAXB and XSTREAM
        kieServicesConfig.setMarshallingFormat(MarshallingFormat.JSON);

        KieServicesClient kieServicesClient = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(kieServicesConfig);

        // Retrieve the RuleServices Client.
        RuleServicesClient rulesClient = kieServicesClient.getServicesClient(RuleServicesClient.class);

        List<Command<?>> commands = new ArrayList<>();

        KieCommands commandFactory = kieServices.getCommands();

        commands.add(commandFactory.newInsert(new RestFlowRequest("Sample"), "SampleRequest"));

        commands.add(commandFactory.newStartProcess("RuleFlowSample.DecisionRestBPM"));
        //commands.add(commandFactory.newFireAllRules("numberOfFiredRules"));
        //ProcessServicesClient processService
        //        = kieServicesClient.getServicesClient(ProcessServicesClient.class);
        //processService.startProcess(CONTAINER_ID,"RuleFlowSample.DecisionRestBPM");

        BatchExecutionCommand batchExecutionCommand = commandFactory.newBatchExecution(commands);
        ServiceResponse<ExecutionResults> response = rulesClient.executeCommandsWithResults(CONTAINER_ID, batchExecutionCommand);
```

It fails to execute the Rest Service Task with following error
[Error Thrown By KIE Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4qBK.png)

If change the code to start process using ProcessServicesClient then Business Process executes without any issue but rules don't execute.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the correct approach using         commands.add(commandFactory.newStartProcess("RuleFlowSample.DecisionRestBPM"));"

I tried it using below code(https://github.com/jbossdemocentral/kie-server-client-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/redhat/demo/qlb/loan_application/Main.java) and it works fine :

KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();

```
    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new EnteredCredentialsProvider(USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    KieServicesConfiguration kieServicesConfig = KieServicesFactory.newRestConfiguration(KIE_SERVER_URL, credentialsProvider);

    // Set the Marshaling Format to JSON. Other options are JAXB and XSTREAM
    kieServicesConfig.setMarshallingFormat(MarshallingFormat.JSON);

    KieServicesClient kieServicesClient = KieServicesFactory.newKieServicesClient(kieServicesConfig);

    // Retrieve the RuleServices Client.
    RuleServicesClient rulesClient = kieServicesClient.getServicesClient(RuleServicesClient.class);

    /*
     * Create the list of commands that we want to fire against the rule engine. In this case we insert 2 objects, applicant and loan,
     * and we trigger a ruleflow (with the StartProcess command).
     */
    List<Command<?>> commands = new ArrayList<>();

    KieCommands commandFactory = kieServices.getCommands();
    //The identifiers that we provide in the insert commands can later be used to retrieve the object from the response.
    commands.add(commandFactory.newInsert(getApplicant(), "applicant"));
    commands.add(commandFactory.newInsert(getLoan(), "loan"));
    commands.add(commandFactory.newStartProcess("loan-application.loan-application-decision-flow"));
```

For testing purpose please remove rest handler and try with script task and see the result.

Comment: Rest Handler is required for the Demo and looks like WorkItemHandler implementation works only with ProcessServicesClient